# Bad vertical spacing in simple fraction

Tags: spacing, fractions

How can I even out the spacing in these fractions?  I have tried `\frac` vs `\dfrac` along with `\strut` and I get similar results:

```
    \[ \bar{x} = \frac{0+1+2+5}{4} = \frac{8}{4} = 2 \]
    \[ \bar{x} = \dfrac{0+1+2+5}{4} = \dfrac{8}{4} = 2 \]
    \[ \bar{x} = \frac{0+1+2+5}{\strut 4} = \frac{8}{\strut 4} = 2 \]
    \[ \bar{x} = \dfrac{0+1+2+5}{\strut 4} = \dfrac{8}{\strut 4} = 2 \]
```

[image: tex output]
The third and fourth (with `\strut`) seem to help but surely you can't be expected to always add `\strut` to simple fractions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What exactly is the spacing matter you're trying to change?

Comment: the fraction bar seems much much closer to the 4 than the 8. I would like it to be in the middle.

Comment: the fraction bar is positioned to accommodate "typical" fraction material with variables, and variables, e.g. `y`, often have descenders, or even subscripts.

Comment: so can I adjust that spacing easily for numerical fractions?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "easily". If you know how to use TeX's low-level `\raise` and `\lower` macros, you probably won't find it difficult to apply adjustments. However, I honestly would *not* attempt to adjust the vertical spacing. As barbara beeton has noted in her comment, the positioning of the material in the numerator and denominator was chosen for "typical" material. You'd need separate treatments of `\frac{a}{b}`, `\frac{b}{a}`, `\frac{x}{y}`, `\frac{y}{x}`, etc. And, you'd risk creating a very uneven ("ransom note") look if you have several fraction expressions side by side.

Comment: is there not a separate fraction function for numerical values?

Comment: Since you seem to prefer the fractions with `strut`s (and I think that should be `mathstrut`), why not just `\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{\frac{#1}{\strut #2}}`? At least, you won't be typing `strut` every time.